# Get all dependencies of a maven project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-profiles

I use

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

to get all dependencies of the project in `target/dependency`
but it doesn't work if one of the sub projects have profiles to select dependencies

```
-project A
  - libA
  - libB
   - libB1(profile A)
   - libBs(profile B)
```

so if I execute the above `mvn` command I get `libA` and `LibB`,
but neither `LibB1` nor `LibB2` but I want *both*, is that possible? Is there a way to activate a profile for dependencies?

Comment: The first wrong way is to have profiles for different dependencies? the question is why do you need such things? Furthermore using for example maven-assembly-plugin to get all dependencies...

Answer (score 1):

You can activate profiles on the command line with `-P`. This allows you to copy all relevant dependencies.

Comment: this does only work If I execute the `pom` file from `libB` but not on `project A` I get `The requested profile "A" could not be activated because it does not exist.`

Comment: I see. There is probably not way to achieve what you want to achieve using the dependency plugin. If this is one-time thing, I would just add the libraries as direct dependencies. If you need a systematic solution, you probably have to craft your own plugin.

Comment: ok, yeah I need for an automated process. I made a "dummy" profile which is the default profile and added all dependencies there, that should work for my purpose, thank you!